# Prove that Binomial Distribution is a discrete distribution?

Tags: probability

I struggled to come up with an approach and I'm not sure if induction is needed. Please help!

EDIT:

Thanks for all the quick feedback!

Is there a way to prove that for a random variable x with a binomial distribution, P(x=0) + P(x=1) + ... + P(x=n) = 1? Possibly through induction?

Comment: It is discrete by its very definition, there is nothing to be proven.

Comment: How can you use induction on non integer points?

Comment: Write down the definition of a binomial distribution. Then write down your definition of a discrete distribution. The rest should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick feedback!

Is there a way to prove that for a random variable x with a binomial distribution, P(x=0) + P(x=1) + ... + P(x=n) = 1? Possibly through induction?

Answer (score 2):

A random variable X is said to have the Binomial distribution with parameters $N,p$ if

> $p(X =x) = \begin{cases} 
>        \binom{N}{x} \,\,p^x \,\,(1-p)^{N-x} & 0 \leq x \leq N \\\\
>               0 & otherwise     \end{cases} $

since  the support of random variable is $\{0,1,2..,N\}$.we can conclude that it is discrete distribution

EDIT:

following is the classic (and elegant) proof if you know [Binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

$ = \sum_{x=0}^N \binom{N}{x} \, p^x \, (1-p)^{N-x}$

$ =\Big( p + 1-p \Big)^N$ ( By binomial expansion )

$ = 1^{N}$

$ = 1$

Comment: oops sorry.edited :)

Comment: Thanks for all the quick feedback!

Is there a way to prove that for a random variable x with a binomial distribution, P(x=0) + P(x=1) + ... + P(x=n) = 1? Possibly through induction?

Comment: I have added you can check now.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ (and $p$) then $P(X\in\{0,1,\dots,n\})=1$.

The set $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ is a countable set.

This together states that binomial distribution can be labeled as a discrete distribution.